# Multiple ListViews in ExpandableListView or nested ListViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have been trying to import multiple Listviews inside another "mother" Listview.

I have a class where the ListViews are created and then the Activity class which call these views. The only thing I managed to do is fill the "mother" with ListPerms@ entries(the objects I guess)

Here is my class for multiple ListViews

```
public ListPerms(Context context, String a, int docid) {
    super(context);
    table=a;
    did=docid;
    list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.specific_perm_list);
    getdata(list,ar_list);
}


private void getdata( ListView list, ArrayList<String> arlist){
    Database openHelper = new Database(getContext());
    myDB = openHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    myDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("data/data/com.example.login2/databases/aeglea", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    try{fill(list,arlist);}catch(Exception e){Log.e("NAT EXISTANT","THIS->"+e);}

}

private void fill( ListView list, ArrayList<String> arlist){
    Cursor temp = null;
    Cursor buffer = null;
    String type_from_table = null;
    String[] items = null;

    if(table=="med") {type_from_table = "medication";}
    if(table=="test") {type_from_table = "test";}
    if(table=="all") {type_from_table = "allergy";}
    if(table=="proc") {type_from_table = "procedure";}
    if(table=="cond") {type_from_table = "condition";}
    if(table=="vacc") {type_from_table = "vaccine";}


    temp = fetchOption("SELECT * FROM permission WHERE did="+did+" AND type='"+type_from_table+"'");
    if(temp.getCount()>0){

        buffer = fetchOption("SELECT * FROM user_"+table+" WHERE id="+temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex("fileid")));
        items = new String[] {buffer.getString(buffer.getColumnIndex("name"))};
        arlist.addAll( Arrays.asList(items) ); 
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.item, arlist); 

        for(int i=1;i<temp.getCount();i++){
            temp.moveToNext();
            buffer = fetchOption("SELECT * FROM user_"+table+" WHERE id="+temp.getString(temp.getColumnIndex("fileid")));
            listAdapter.add(buffer.getString(buffer.getColumnIndex("name"))); 
        }

        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }else{
        items = new String[] { "None."}; 
        arlist.addAll( Arrays.asList(items) ); 
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.item, arlist);
        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

And the Activity class follows where(now) I have an ExpandableListView, but I'm really noob to understand how ELV works

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.docp);
        general = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.Tot_perm_list);
    //random data
}
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    ListPerms me = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"med",did);
    ListPerms te = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"test",did);
    ListPerms all = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"all",did);
    ListPerms proc = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"proc",did);
    ListPerms cond = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"cond",did);
    ListPerms vacc = new ListPerms(getApplicationContext(),"vacc",did);

    me.setActivated(isChild());
    te.setActivated(isChild());
    all.setActivated(isChild());
    proc.setActivated(isChild());
    cond.setActivated(isChild());
    vacc.setActivated(isChild());
    list.add(me);
    list.add(te);
    list.add(all);
    list.add(proc);
    list.add(cond);
    list.add(vacc);

    general.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    general.addChildrenForAccessibility(list);
    //what do I do
}
```

Advice on how to do ListView{LV,Lv ... } or ExpandableListView{LV, LV ....}

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding it's not a good idea to incorporate two or more list views into one. You'll definitely have issues with scrolling (of course, some dirty hacks can help to fix it) and probably, performance will be way worst than for single list.

I would suggest You to go with ExpandableList and ExpandableListAdapter. To make lists into one You will need to compose it's adapters.
e.g. it could looks like the following:

```
...
// Your implementation of ExpandableListAdapter

// To store all 'child' adapters, it should be filled by the owner
SparseArray<BaseAdapter> mChildAdapters = new SparseArray<BaseAdapter>();

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final BaseAdapter childAdapter = mChildAdapters.get(groupPosition);
    View view = null;

    if (childAdapter != null) {
        view = childAdapter.getView(childPosition, convertView, parent);
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int childrenCount = 0;
    final BaseAdapter childAdapter = mChildAdapters.get(groupPosition);

    if (childAdapter != null) {
        childrenCount = mChildAdapter.getCount();
    }

    return childrenCount;
}
...
```

Please note, the above code is just a draft, but I hope the idea is clear from it. The only trick You've might face with this approach - `convertView` You've received in one childAdapter might be from another, so some (quite trivial) checks should be applied before reusing convertView.

Also, expandable list would give you nice possibility to provide every list with the header (via groupView).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. I can't see how to populate an ExpandableListView with data instead of parsing data as many ListViews

Comment: hm, You can create e.g. asynctask to create child adapters and prepare data for them. Or do it via http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html - CursorLoader and add new child adapters to mChildAdapters  then data is ready (one by one) - this would elluminate empty screens.